# Is my printer broken after years of no use?

Tags: printing, printer, inkjet-printer

It's a Brother DCP-330C inkjet printer that was not used for more than 3 years. After using the printer's auto cleaning feature, this is what I get (it's Windows' print test page, but with nothing black, and colors look weird):

[image: Windows XP test print page]

I removed the ink cartridges and they are all about half full. The magenta one was leaking through the hole that connects it to the printer. After putting them back and auto-cleaning again, the test print result is the same.

I could try buying new cartridges but if that doesn't work I would buy them for nothing... do you think this is a printer problem or a cartridge problem?

Comment: With inkjet printers I _always_ look to the cartridges first; long-unused cartridges tend to dry out and/or the nozzles get plugged with the dried-out ink. It's why when I last needed a new printer, I opted for the more expensive laser instead of an inkjet.

Comment: It depends on whether the ink cartridge includes the print head or of they simply feed into another area. If the cartridge is the print head then replacing it will fix the problem. If not then it might be that you need to take the head assembly out and flush it through to clean it, and then use fresh cartridges.

Comment: As a low-use printer consumer, after 10 years of this constant battle with dried-out print heads, I finally bit the bullet & went laser. 15 years & two printers later, I have never ever had a clogged head [it just cannot happen] which also means I have never wasted paper or ink trying to fix it. When the ink [toner] finally ran out after 10 years on the first one, it was actually cheaper [& made more long-term sense re support/drivers etc] to buy the second printer new than refill the toner.

Comment: The print head might be clogged with dried ink. Clean it thoroughly under a very hot water jet until the ink stops running out, then let it fully dry before reinstalling. The computer-side maintenance tasks for the printer cannot fix this problem.

Comment: @Tetsujin New printers usually come with a lot less toner than what new full cartridges contain, so paying more for toner may save money in the long run if compared to getting a new printer.

Comment: @svin83 - agreed. My first printer had full cartridges, my current one came with 'halves'. I did say I was low-use though. This is after 6 years' use [I double-checked the purchase date] - 70% colours, 80% black remaining… https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Hyf9.png Plenty of life in it yet, & it will never dry out. ;) This compared to buying ink at least once a year for my old inkjets, whether I'd used it all or not, & the reams of paper trying to unclog the heads every time, equates to a massive saving over 15 years. Plus, every time I want to use it, it **works**.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to run the cleaning cycle multiple times to un-clog the jets. However, if the printer has not been used for 3 years, there is a good chance they are not recoverable. That's one of the problems with inkjets: if you don't use them regularly, they expire on you. That's just one reason why I use lasers. They're also faster, and cheaper to run.

At this stage there are 2 things you can do:

1. Clean until you're out of ink; then buy a laser.
2. If you can remove the printhead altogether, soak the jets in a
   mixture of alcohol and water, as detailed [here](https://www.wikihow.com/Clean-Print-Heads#Using-Manual-Cleaning). If that fails, buy a laser.